# How do I center align floated elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper having a series of divs inside it in the form of boxes. 
Here are some problems that I am facing.
When I resize the window, the elements appear to be left aligned. How do I centrally align them.

Also, another problem is that the size of the divs slightly vary, which misaligns them.

**[Here is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ges6t4b/)**

```
.left_wrapper       
{            
    max-width: 70%;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
}


.boxa
    {
    background-color: #45e645;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    left:4%;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 1%;
    padding:1%;
    font-size: 85px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid green;

}




<div class="left_wrapper" id="roll_nos">
    <div id="box" class="boxa">01</div>
    <div id="box" class="boxa">02</div>
    <div id="box" class="boxa">03</div>
    <div id="box" class="boxa">04</div>
     .............
     .............
     .............
     .............

</div>
```

As suggested, the question is NOT a duplicate of the above mentioned question, though the problem is (only) similar to the one presented there.

The accepted and most upvoted answer is not applicable in my case because I want the elements to automatically move to next line when the window is resized.
 Thanks to '@Niet the Dark Absol', The flex-wrap solution is working to center align the elements, but a slight misalignment still lies there, the red line near #13 highlights it.[image: Please Note the red line is far from <code>13</code>.]

Comment: You should use flex instead.

Comment: Use inline-block instead of float https://jsfiddle.net/2ges6t4b/1/

Comment: no please, my problem is different. please see the fiddle, resize the window and then notice the problem.

Comment: [Flex works better](https://jsfiddle.net/2ges6t4b/2/)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that seems to be working. :)

Comment: Ok, so to make all elements centered, you have to remove floating from your wrapper element. What goes for different boxes being floated to next level, not floating - it's all because you didn't specify actual width. If you won't have a width you can always expect different types of misbehavior. If you need your boxes to grow in size when container is growing - use percentage, if not - have a fixed width. Also get rid of 1% padding, more small percentages you use - less neat result you will get.

Comment: try giving width and you shall laugh at the results. Also, removing float is strictly against the spirit of this question.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, But still a slight misalignment is there if you observe the fiddle,  https://jsfiddle.net/2ges6t4b/2/  for instance, Kindly note that #13's right border is slightly mis-aligned. How to fix that.

Comment: @RameshPareek I'm not seeing any border issue there...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, Kindly see the added image above

Comment: for vary div size I recoomend add ".boxa { min-width: 85px; }"

Comment: I have moved the code which was in the question into a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so it can be run on this page. Please copy the rest of your code from your JSFiddle into the question (due to copyright reasons, only you can do this). Without enough code to duplicate the problem *in the question itself*, (i.e. a [mcve]) the question is off-topic. Off-topic questions may be put on hold and closed if not [edit]ed to be on-topic.

Comment: thanks @BrunoBG, It works.

Comment: @BrunoBg, please answer the question

Comment: I glad help @RameshPareek - Q and what or where is your next question?

Comment: @BrunoBG, I am talking about this very question. Your technique worked, now please convert your comment into an answer. :)

Comment: OK @RameshPareek here you are, I'll wait for your upvote. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your vary div size "red line aligment" I recommend add:

```
.boxa { 
    min-width: 85px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this without `float:left` code I found okay from my PC And browser !

```
.left_wrapper       
  {            
    max-width: 70%;
    margin:0 auto;
 }
```